# Words/expressions for achieving the most wins

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests

I am looking for words or expressions that I can use to describe the most successful team/individual in a tournament/competition (having won it the most times, like Brazil at the FIFA World Cup.) One word I can think of is "most-decorated", but that seems to only apply if the winning team receives a major award for and it wouldn't be as appropriate if it's a gaming/chess tournament. I am also aware of the term "winningest", but that sounds awkward and really informal. Appreciate any suggestions.

Comment: I was going to suggest "Most successful", only to find it in your question. What's wrong with "most successful"?

Comment: FYI, "most-decorated" just means the team with the most medals/awards, not one that wins some kind of special award. So it can also be used in the way you intend.

Comment: "Most-decorated" sounds like the description of a float in the Rose Parade or a military person being honored for outstanding service. I wouldn't use it in sports.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Winningest**, or if you want to go all-in,  **All-time winningest**.

> Don Shula won 392 games in 26 years as the head coach of the Miami Dolphins. Combined with the 98 wins he racked up in seven years with the Baltimore Colts, Shula is the winningest coach in NFL history with 490 victories.

http://www.foxsports.com/collegebasketball/gallery/winningest-coaches-in-sports-history-111511

> All-time winningest Division I basketball coaches

http://www.newsday.com/sports/college/college-basketball/all-time-winningest-division-i-basketball-coaches-1.3377215

Answer (score 2):

**Reigned** and **ruled** can be used in similar sense but only when you are talking about a **span of time**.

**Example:** Michael Phelps ruled the swimming world from 2000 to 2016.